# Json to C# Deserialize - Property name is an int - how to fix?

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I'm trying to get data from an API, and it works. This is the data I get:

[image: json data]

Yet the only problem is, when I try to access the "7" and "10" property in order to get "rankPoints", I get a bug:

> Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: 'The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'System.Console.WriteLine(string, params object[])' and 'System.Console.WriteLine(char[])''

This is the code that works:

```
var x = oMycustomclassname["rankedSeasons"];
```

This is the code that does not work:

```
var x = oMycustomclassname["rankedSeasons.7.10.rankPoints"];
```

I'm guessing it cant access the property because it is an int? But I cant change the data, since it is from an API.

Comment: The problem is in the code where you write it to the console, not the deserialization. What does the debugger say the value and type of `x` is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

every sub item is another json object which can be accessed like a dictionary

```
var x = (int)oMycustomclassname["rankedSeasons"]["7"]["10"]["rankPoints"];
```

Comment: Thank you! This was just what I needed, and it works perfectly. I cannot thank you enough @Eser!